# Getting an object and its attribute in Ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm struggling to do some of the simplest tasks in Ember data - getting hold of a model object and reading its attributes.

I just figured out to get a model's attribute, you can do `App.Model.find(id).get('attr_name')`.

`App.Model.find(id)` does not return an object, but a class (a Promise) instead.

What is the proper way of obtaining the object? Or perhaps do you not get the object ever, but just [getting or setting](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/modifying-attributes/) the attributes of the object instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the proper way of obtaining the object?

Pass a success function to the model promise returned by `find(id)`:

```
App.Model.find(1).then(function(record) {
  console.log('Found record: ', record.toString());
  console.log('Inspecting record...', Em.inspect(record));
  console.log('Serializing record...', record.serialize());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update after the [Ember Data updates](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#elimination-of-modelfind-and-modelcreaterecord) in Sept 2013:

To get the attribute of an object identified by its ID in the router or the controller, do:

```
this.store.find('model', 'insert_id_of_obj').then(function(obj){
    console.log(obj.get('insert_attribute_name'))
});
```

If you want to test it in the console, do:

```
App.__container__.lookup('store:main').find('model', 'insert_id_of_obj').then(function(obj){
    console.log(obj.get('insert_attribute_name'))
});
```